# How to load a gem's schema in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I load a schema that a Gem provides?

It would be nice to load something like this but it does not work.

```
rake db:schema:load:gem_schema
```

Comment: Typically these instructions will be found in the gem's install documentation. For example, [`paper_trail` uses `rails generate`](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#1b-installation). I don't think there's a universally agreed method. Which gem are you trying to install?

Comment: It’s a custom gem. We use the schema for testing a database and would love to use that in a project that includes that gem.

Comment: I'd suggest surveying how other gems do it. I prefer gems which make it part of the normal migration process like paper_trail does.